# React Native Swipeout performance issues

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-native-flatlist

I have been using the swipeout library in my app for couple of months now. I was aware it will be much slower on simulators but kept it. Now that I have released the signed APK version I can see an extreme difference between performance of this library on say iPhone X versus Samsung S6. What could I do to make this work less laggy? The structure is like this:

I have a flatlist, which has a nested flatlist. The nested flatlist has swipeout rows. It has 2 buttons both on left and right. I am blocking the scroll of the parent flatlist whenever buttons are in view (after onOpen).

Comment: Not sure that this relates 100% as I am not using swipeout, but switching from pure function to PureComponents speed up my app significantly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To anyone experiencing this problem, here is the cause and the solution: 
Cause: Extra renders that were caused by updating flat list scroll prop (I was locking the vertical scroll in the onOpen from swipeout).
Fix: Get rid of extra renders eliminating them in the shouldComponentUpdate. To prevent full list re-render when setting the scroll prop you can use the setNativeProps function.
Good luck to all!